# How do I attach additional labels to each side of a radio element in Formidable Forms (in Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, radio-button, formidable

How do I attach additional labels on each side of a radio button question like in the image below ("INTE BRA" and "MYCKET BRA"):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot7fy.jpg

(I have Formidable Forms Pro)

EDIT: I am also curious on how to align the option label (1,2,3,4,5,6) to the top of the buttons as shown in the image, for the moment they're to the right of the radio buttons which I believe is default.

Comment: `:before`, `:after`. But in the example, you provided, it looks like there is a simple table.

Comment: Where would I find this simple table? :)

Answer (score 0):

To align the label, you need to change the 'Label Position' in the field options. To add additional labels, you can either customize the form HTML (in the form's settings), or use CSS :before and :after selectors.